# React HMR does not render even though an update is detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

I have the following in my `index.jsx`:

```
const store = configureStore();
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes />
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('routes.jsx', () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render();
  });
}
render();
```

This renders the initial app. Now when I change any file, I get the following log in the browser's console.

```
[HMR] bundle rebuilding
[HMR] bundle rebuilt in 285ms
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./src/js/components/SomeComponent/SomeComponent.jsx
[HMR]  - ./src/js/components/App.jsx
[HMR]  - ./src/js/routes.jsx
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

This log suggests that the update was detected and that the modules were updated. Also, I see in the "network" tab that a new script is loaded and the `<head>` tag flashes showing it loaded the new script. I checked the script and it contains my changes.

Yet, I don't see my page update. The whole page does a quick flash to show that the `render()` function gets called but the changes are not present.

I'm using most of my HMR and webpack setup from https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.

I'm stumped as to where to look to find out what happened. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I just found that `module.hot.accept()` is only called one time, for the first update. It's not being called the second time I make a change to the files.

EDIT 2:

When I try using module.hot.accept(() => {}), it seems to work but then the reducers are not working and I'm getting this error:

> Provider does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

So, the only way I can do anything about this is by having two `module.hot.accept`s one with `App.jsx` and other with `reducers.jsx`. Still no luck figuring out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: which router npm are you using? Also include how your handling the routes

Comment: Does that matter?

Comment: Check out my working HMR boilerplate (master branch comes with react-hot-module installed): https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate

Comment: I'm not using `react-hot-loader` in my project, just the webpack HMR plugin. Thanks for the link though, it's looking neat.

Comment: I actually ended up using `react-hot-loader` to solve this. I couldn't find what's wrong with my current setup , Thanks for the tip @mattcarlotta

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

For anyone in the future, did you try this?

```
//My root component (that also use redux), but can be any component one by one in case you want to specific compontents with hot reload


import {hot} from "react-hot-loader/root"
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { ExtReact } from '@sencha/ext-react' 

import store from "./redux/store"
import Layout from './Layout';

// Enable responsiveConfig app-wide. You can remove this if you don't plan to build a responsive UI.

/**
 * The main application view
 */



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Layout />
        </Provider>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default hot(App);
```

Comment: There is also a variant, for when you want to hot reload your components one by one 


     `import {hot} from "react-hot-loader ` with `export default hot(module)(**your compontent**) `